# overriding two methods in a subclass

Tags: objective-c

Here is my first custom class' implementation

first header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRStockHolding : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) float purchaseSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic) float currentSharePrice;
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfShares;
-(float)costInDollars;
-(float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

first implementation

```
#import "BNRStockHolding.h"

@implementation BNRStockHolding

-(float)costInDollars{
    float cost = [self purchaseSharePrice]*[self numberOfShares];
    return cost;
}

-(float)valueInDollars{
    float value = [self currentSharePrice]*[self numberOfShares];
    return value;
}

@end
```

Subclass header
    #import 
    #import "BNRStockHolding.h"

```
@interface BNRForeignStockHolding : BNRStockHolding

@property (nonatomic) float converstionRate;

@end
```

Here is the subclass' implementation

```
#import "BNRForeignStockHolding.h"

@implementation BNRForeignStockHolding

-(float)costInDollars{
    float normalCost = [super costInDollars];
    return normalCost*[self converstionRate];
}

-(float)valueInDollars{
    float normalValue = [super valueInDollars];
    return normalValue*[self converstionRate];
}

@end
```

main

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRForeignStockHolding.h"


int main

(int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    @autoreleasepool {

        BNRStockHolding *AAPL = [[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];
        BNRStockHolding *GOOG = [[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];
        BNRStockHolding *NYSE = [[BNRStockHolding alloc]init];

        NSMutableArray *stockArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        AAPL.purchaseSharePrice=2.30;
        AAPL.currentSharePrice=4.50;
        AAPL.numberOfShares=40;
        [stockArray addObject:AAPL];


        GOOG.purchaseSharePrice=12.19;
        GOOG.currentSharePrice=10.56;
        GOOG.numberOfShares=90;
        [stockArray addObject:GOOG];


        NYSE.purchaseSharePrice=45.10;
        NYSE.currentSharePrice=49.51;
        NYSE.numberOfShares=210;
        [stockArray addObject:NYSE];

        BNRForeignStockHolding *conv = [[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc]init];
        conv.converstionRate = 0.5;


        for (BNRForeignStockHolding *d in stockArray)
        {
            float currentTotalPrice = d.costInDollars;
            float purchasedTotalPrice = d.valueInDollars;

            NSLog(@"Purchased:$%f \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Valued:$%f",currentTotalPrice, purchasedTotalPrice);



        }



    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to override the methods costInDollars and valueInDollars in the subclass .m while implementing a conversionRate to the floats.

my main is taking them methods from the original class, not the subclass, and they're not being overridden.

sorry - thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show where you're instantiating the objects and calling the methods.  Also, is there more code to these classes that you're not showing?

Comment: edit'd and added the rest of the code. i'm literally always down-voted for asking questions. any reason why?

Comment: Likely because we don't know what the problem is

Comment: You haven't stated a problem or asked a question.

Comment: The first and foremost requirement is to clearly state what problem you're experiencing or what question you have.  This is even more important than including code.

Comment: So the question is???

Comment: whoa i disturbed the bee hive. the original question had gotten lost in the last edit - my apologies. it's there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply casting each type to `BNRForeignStockHolding` won't change their concrete types.  In the provided code, you only add `BNRStockHolding` instances to the NSArray. The reason you can get past the compiler in the enhanced for loop is because of dynamic binding -- NSArray's do not have any knowledge of type, so the compiler can only assume they are full of id's. The reason you are allowed to access `costInDollars` at runtime is because the base class happens to respond to that selector, but they are NOT the of type `BNRForeignStockHolding` at runtime.

You need to change all of your `[[BNRStockHolding alloc] init]`'s to `[[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc] init]` and set the `conversionRate` on each instance if you want those results.

**Alternative**

If `conversionRate` can be global, then you can add a class getter/setter.

Ex. in BNRForeignStockHolding.m:

```
static _conversionRate;
+ (void)setConversionRate:(float)conversionRate {
    _conversionRate = conversionRate;
}

+ (float)conversionRate {
    return _conversionRate;
}
```

and then in the instance methods:

```
-(float)costInDollars{
    float normalCost = [super costInDollars];
    return normalCost*[self.class conversionRate];
}

-(float)valueInDollars{
    float normalValue = [super valueInDollars];
    return normalValue*[self.class conversionRate];
}
```

and within your implementation:

```
[BNRForeignStockHolding setConversionRate:0.5];
```

Comment: Awesome I had that actually a little while ago. However, now all my outputs are $0.000, $0.000, etc,etc. Any suggestions? Do I need to introduce the properties again in BNRForeignStockHolding.h?

Comment: Had a bit of a typo at the end...sorry bout that.

Comment: Awesome - that worked. For some reason I had thought that I could  init & set conversionRate once and it would be returned through the loop. Thanks, i'd upvote you if I could.

Comment: @imnotuser3006354 I added an example of how you _could_ implement that.

Comment: i'll take that into consideration as well. cheers.

Comment: @imnotuser3006354 - It needs to be noted that if conversionRate is a property or instance variable it needs to be set in *every* instance of your subclass.  It won't magically jump from one object instance to another.  John's "alternative" example shows it converted to a static, so it's globally available.  But this won't work if you want to have more than one conversion rate.